# meaning of the phrase "follow oneself up on something in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/Na5ERTBpVqY). It is at 14 minute and 23 second.

> There is also a cardio component in all sports. Even you could make a nitpicky argument that powerlifting and weightlifting have some marginal cardio components, like if you can't **follow yourself up on a lift**, you are probably not going to do as well as you could.

Comment: I think your guess is as good as ours.  It sounds like powerlifting jargon.

Comment: Can you suppose what "lift" means in this context?

Comment: Notice how this pattern complements **follow ... up** with a prepositional phrase complement: *I'll have a shot a whiskey and follow it up **with a beer chaser**.*  So possibly here the meaning is "...can't follow yourself up *with another lift*" taking "yourself" as meaning "what you've just done", that is, your first lift.  But who knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the term 'follow yourself up' is weightlifting jargon which originated from the way competitions are run. 
Competitors are placed in a order. Every time the weight is raised, each competitor is asked in that same order if they want to attempt the new weight or not. They often decline because they are limited on all attempts at any weight, usually three. Those who fail at a weight get another opportunity to attempt it.

So, it becomes possible for a competitor to "follow themselves up" if they were the last to attempt one weight, they want to attempt the next weight, but other others decline to attempt it.